# MongoDb Date error Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

i'm experiencing problem on a BasicQuery with Sping

Here is my query :

```
 public List<Voyage> getVoyages(String destination, Date datedebut, int duree)
            throws MongoException {
        Query query = new Query();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(datedebut);
        c.add(Calendar.DATE,duree);

        BasicQuery q= new BasicQuery("{$or : [{paysDestination : {$elemMatch : {nom : '"+destination+"'}}},{paysPrincipal : {nom : '"+destination+"'}}], debut : {$lte : {$date : "+datedebut+"}}, fin : {$gte : {$date : "+c.getTime()+"}}}");

         return mongoTemplate.find(q, Voyage.class);
    }
```

I have documents on  my database, but i don't receive anyone, my list is empty. In addition, i don't catch any MongoException ...

Have you got an solution ?

Comment: i think date should be put as is in the query instead of making it a string !

Comment: can you write what you're talking about please ? i don't really see ... Thanks

Comment: in your mongo shell query you give your date as is, but in java you force date to be converted in string by concatenating with query string.

Comment: Ok so i should not use BasicQuery object ... i'm going to try it

Comment: Still doesn't work ...

Comment: can you post what did you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a compromise, with mixing BasicQuery with Criteria:

```
BasicQuery q = new BasicQuery("{$or : [{paysDestination : {$elemMatch : {nom : '"+destination+"'}}},{paysPrincipal : {nom : '"+destination+"'}}]}");
q.addCriteria(Criteria.where("debut").lte(datedebut).and("fin").gte(c.getTime()));
```

If you still have any solution for only coding it with BasicQuery, don't hesitate !

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for this:
`{<dateField>: ISODate("2022-01-24")}`
works.
As does:
`{<dateField>: ISODate("2022-01-24T13:40:00.000Z")}`